# Combine all NotBlank error messages in Symfony2

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm trying to combine all NotBlank error messages into one.

If the error array contains at least 1 error that is a NotBlank type, I want it to display only one message like  "Please fill in all fields."

How can I do this?

Here's my twig code

```
 {{form_start(form, {'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}})}}
    <div>
        {{form_widget(form.firstName)}}
        {{form_widget(form.lastName)}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{form_widget(form.username)}}
        {{form_widget(form.email)}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{form_widget(form.password.first, {'attr' : { 'placeholder' : 'Password' } })}}
        {{form_widget(form.password.second, {'attr' : { 'placeholder' : 'Confirm Password' } })}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{form_label(form.birthday)}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{form_widget(form.birthday)}}
    </div>

    <div>
        {{form_widget(form.gender)}}
    </div>

     <div>
        {{form_widget(form.save)}}
    </div>

    {{ form_errors(form.firstName) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.lastName) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.password.first) }}

    {{form_end(form)}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a CallbackValidator

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

and in the `validate` method, check if at least one of the desired fields is blank, and if true, call

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    if(empty($this->field1) || empty($this->field2)) {
        $context->addViolation($message);
    }
}
```

This way you will receive a global form error.