# Symfony combine same ConstraintViolation in one error message

Tags: validation, symfony

How to combine same Constraint violations so I have only one error message.
If all fields are empty I have to show one error message.
This is my class.

```
/**
 * @Assert\GroupSequence({"Required", "Username"})
 */
class Credentials
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Required"})
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"Required"})
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"Username"})
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Required"})
     * @Assert\NotNull(groups={"Required"})
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Assert\Email(groups={"Required"})
     */
    private $confirmPassword;

    // ...
}
```

This is how I'm validating it and in errors I have three ConstraintViolation of type `NotBlank`.

```
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAnnotationMapping()
    ->getValidator();

$errors = $validator->validate($credentials);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine all NotBlank error messages in Symfony2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965294/combine-all-notblank-error-messages-in-symfony2)

Comment: If i use this i have to check manually if fields are empty (which i don't like) so i don't need NotBlank and NotNull  anymore then if fields have some values then i'll have to check manually if they are valid emails (which i don't like) and i will remove Email too also i need to know which fields are invalid

Comment: The `$errors` var is an instance of `ConstraintViolationList`and each violation is an instance of `ConstraintViolation` which has methods like:  `getConstraint()`, `getPropertyPath()`, `getMessage()`, etc., so you could classify and merge these violations to show one error message.